# Django test client get returns 404 however works in shell

Tags: python, django

This is my first test in Django - it's a simple view test to assert that the response in 200.

I'm using the authentication so I'm creating a test user in the first place:

```
class SettingsTests(TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()
    self.username = 'test_user'
    self.email = 'test@whatever.com'
    self.password = 'test'
    self.user = User.objects.create_user(self.username, self.email, self.password)


def tearDown(self):

    self.user.delete()
```

Here's the actual test where I'm trying to test the view:

```
def test_settings_view_is_diplayed_correctly(self):

    login = self.client.login(username = self.username, password = self.password)
    response = self.client.get('/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

This always returns 404, however if I try the same in the `shell` it works and returns 200!

Can somebody please tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: Please show the view that is returning 404.

Comment: @Alasdair - you nailed the problem! The view had a get_object_or_404 shortcut which is causing this problem! My mistake! Thanks a lot for your suggestion! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as suggested by Alasdair was the view. I had a get_object_or_404 shortcut and did not provide the needed object. Hence, the view was returning 404 and the test was failing...