# Django test client get returns 404 instead of 200

Tags: python, django, testing

I'm very new to Django and testing....

I'm testing my app and every time I do `threads_page = self.client.get('/threads/1/')` it returns a 404 status instead of 200 (that url works, the 1 is the subject id).

I found a thread with the same problem and there was a response with the issue ([Django test client get returns 404 however works in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36487311/django-test-client-get-returns-404-however-works-in-shell?answertab=active#tab-top)) but I still don't know how to solve it. 
The problem is that in my views I have a get_object_or_404 with an argument but I don't know how to pass the argument in the test:

views.py

```
def threads(request, subject_id):
    subject = get_object_or_404(Subject, pk=subject_id)
    return render(request, 'forum/threads.html', {'subject': subject})
```

This is my test right now

```
def test_check_threads_content_is_correct(self):
    threads_page = self.client.get('/threads/1/')
    self.assertEqual(threads_page.status_code, 200)
```

Thank you!

*This is my code in Github in case it helps
https://github.com/IreneG5/we_are_social_forum

Comment: use `reverse()` function, add `name` for url in your app `urls.py` and `namespace` in your project `urls.py`. Then `url = reverse('<namespace>:<name>')`..

Comment: I tried but I'm getting more errors now... could you post the full lines of code please?   
Instead of `threads_page = self.client.get('/threads/1/')` you suggest `threads_page = reverse('threads:threads')   
And in the threads/urls.py  `url(r'^threads/(?P<subject_id>\d+)/$', forum_views.threads, name='threads')`   
And in myproject/urls.py  `url(r'^threads/(?P<subject_id>\d+)/$', forum_views.threads, include('threads/(?P<subject_id>\d+)/$.urls', namespace='threads'))`.   
I didn't have an url.py in my app (threads) before, everything is under the project urls.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had very similar issues. I never really found a problem and resorted to having 2 urls - one with the parameter and one without. In views.py I change `def threads(request, subject_id):` to `def threads(request, subject_id=None):` and then add at the top of the function:

```
if not subject_id:
    subject_id = request.GET.get('subject')
```

and in my test:

```
threads_page = self.client.get('/threads/', {'subject': '1'})
```

If someone has an answer that works with parameters in the URLs then take that answer instead - and I will use it too! But if not, then this should get the job done.

One more important part to Django testing - **the test database**.

The testing normally uses a separate, starts off empty with every test, database. There are a couple of ways of putting data into the database. The basic concept is that by running the tests on a "test database" instead of the production database, you can precisely control exactly what is in the database so that your testing will be consistent and so that any tests (e.g., test of a delete) won't mess up your production data. It took me a while to understand it all myself. The Django docs explain a lot of this, though not always so clearly. But if you have tests that expect data, even if it is data that you have had in the regular database "forever", it won't be in the test database unless you somehow specifically add it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried id but didn't work for me, still getting 404 :S

Comment: Did you (after changing the urls file) try manually the URL `/threads/?subject=1` (or similar) to make sure it works that way (so that hopefully the test will to)?

Comment: I hadn't changed the urls file. 
I changed it now to `url(r'^threads/?subject=1', forum_views.threads, name='threads')` (I'm not sure if it's right), and nothing, now I'm getting error in other templates that need subject_id.

Comment: Add a 2nd URL. You should have one that is ^threads/somesortofregexthatmapstosubject and another that is just ^threads/$

Comment: I did that and it works in the browser, but still getting 404 in the test.   
I'm using the debugger to see the values and all I can see in threads_page.container is '<h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL /threads/1/ was not found on this server.</p>'  
Even hardcoding the urls in urls.py and the request results on that. 
Any idea?

Comment: If it works in the browser as BOTH `/threads/1` and `/threads/?subject=1` then you have urls.py correct. Once you have urls correct, you need to make sure the **test** uses `/threads/` with `{'subject': '1'}` instead of `/threads/1`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, but I still get the Not Found. The URL is constructed properly as it's looking for URL /threads/1/ but it says it was not found. 
I'm not sure how that works... Is it looking for a template there or something like that? Because there isn't a template there. The template forum/threads.html extends base.html and also calls inside another template forum/thread_item.html to list all the threads under that subject.

Comment: The test should **NOT** be looking for /threads/1. Can you list the latest version of `test_check_threads_content_is_correct`?

Comment: test.py-
    `def test_check_threads_content_is_correct(self):
        threads_page = self.client.get('/threads/', {'subject': '1'})
        self.assertEqual(threads_page.status_code, 200)`
views.py-
`def threads(request, subject_id=None):
    if not subject_id:
        subject_id = request.GET.get('subject')
    subject = get_object_or_404(Subject, pk=subject_id)
    return render(request, 'forum/threads.html', {'subject': subject})`
  urls.py-
`url(r'^threads/$', forum_views.threads, name='threads'),
 url(r'^threads/(?P<subject_id>\d+)/$', forum_views.threads, name='threads')`

Comment: Does your test database (either because you added it originally and it is persistent, or because you add it in the test setup function) have a Subject with pk=1?

Comment: Yes, it does, and it works perfectly in the browser. It shows all the threads under that subject

Comment: The table in the database is called threads_subject, can that be causing the problem?

Comment: Table name is normal - app_model. The testing normally uses a separate, starts off empty with every test, database. There are a couple of ways of putting data into the database. The basic concept is that by running the tests on a "test database" instead of the production database, you can precisely control exactly what is in the database so that your testing will be consistent *and* so that any tests (e.g., test of a delete) won't mess up your production data. It took me a while to understand it all myself. The Django docs explain a lot of this, though not always so clearly.

Comment: After hours of thinking what's happening... you just made me think about the database... I didn't add the fixtures to this text so it's normal that it didn't find the url. It works now :)
Thanks a million for your help and sorry for the time wasted.

Comment: You're welcome, just please accept the answer. I will add the database part to the main answer for future reference by others.

Comment: Now I got another problem.... 
`def test_check_threads_content_is_correct(self):
     threads_page = self.client.get('/threads/1/')
     self.assertEqual(threads_page.status_code, 200)
     self.assertTemplateUsed(threads_page, "forum/threads.html")
     threads_page_template_output = render_to_response("forum/threads.html", {'subject_id': 1}).content
        self.assertEqual(threads_page.content, threads_page_template_output)`
the threads_page_template_output doesn't 'pick up' the subject id, how do I pass that argument here? I need to compare the 2 outputs for that subject id

Comment: Based on your main function, it looks like it should be `{'subject': 1}` not `subject_id`. Beyond that though, I have not tried to compare the entire output, just template, status and context items passed to the template/render, so I am not sure whether that should work or not.

Comment: It does not work with {'subject':1} either but I got a workaround, not sure if it's totally right but I set up self.subject_id to 1 and then `subject = get_object_or_404(Subject, pk=self.subject_id)` and then pass that subject instead of just the 1 to the render _to_response. `threads_page_template_output = render_to_response("forum/threads.html", {'subject': subject}).content`  I guess I needed to pass the full object and not just the id.

Comment: this solution might be related to " Passing mutable default arguments to functions (i.e. an empty list)". Default arguments are evaluated once when the function is defined, not each time the function is called. This means that if you use a mutable default argument (such as a list) and mutate it, you will and have mutated that object for all future calls to the function as well.